# Why nut with gasket on tile cutter wheel?

Tags: tile

I just purchased this replacement cutter wheel for a Sigma tile cutter:

[image]

You're supposed to put the bolt in the device with the wheel so the bolt acts as the axis. My 2 questions are:

1. What's the purpose of the gasket on the nut?
2. Which side am I supposed to put the gasket on? Facing the wheel, or facing away from the wheel?

Comment: It's possible to thread a nut like this on nylon-side-first, but it's pretty difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nylon insert lock nuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyloc_nut) are the full name of the nut. The Nylon inside the nut prevents the nut from working itself off the bolt due to friction and compression. You would want to install the nut with the round side facing away from the bolt head.